# Is this a bug in Rails validations or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

This involves validations on a join table, validating the activerecord on either side of the join against each other. It seems to not behave as expected, allowing a violation of the validation.

I want to allow users to be able to belong to groups, (or groups to users, as it's a many-to-many). But the user's company must match the group's company. Hence, `UserGroup` looks like this:

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  validate :group_company_matches_user_company


  private
  def group_company_matches_user_company
    if user.company != group.company
      self.errors.add(:group, "company must match user company")
    end
  end
end
```

Now here is a test showing the failure of the validation:

```
test 'validation failure example' do
    group = groups(:default)
    user = users(:manager)

    #default user and group have the same company in the DB
    assert_equal user.company, group.company

    #create a 2nd company
    company2 = user.company.dup
    assert_difference 'Company.count', 1 do
      company2.save!
    end

    #set the group's company to the new one, verify user and group's company don't match
    group.company = company2    
    assert_not_equal user.company, group.company

    #WARNING!!! this passes and creates a new UserGroup. even though it violates
    #the UserGroup validation
    assert_difference 'UserGroup.count', 1 do
      group.users << user
    end

    #What about when we save the group to the DB?
    #no issues.
    group.save

    #this will fail. we have saved a UserGroup who's user.company != group.company
    #despite the validation that requires otherwise
    UserGroup.all.each do |ug|
      assert_equal ug.user.company.id, ug.group.company.id
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this `collection << object` TL:DR bypasses validation

> Adds one or more objects to the collection by setting their foreign
>   keys to the collection’s primary key. Note that this operation
>   instantly fires update sql without waiting for the save or update call
>   on the parent object.